# How do I change my Google Account in Beyondpod?

Tags: google-account, accounts

How do I change my Google Account in [Beyondpod](http://www.beyondpod.mobi/android/), the podcatcher? The one used to synchronize with Google Reader I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the feeds screen click menu > more > import and export feeds.  Once you are in there you should see the option to change the email.